# XRP send function does not work. The latest ledger sequence 36750915 is greater than the transaction's LastLedgerSequence

Tags: javascript, xrp

This is my xrpl function. It comes from the xrpl tutorial and should work.
But it returns tefBAD_AUTH error.

I am writing the xrpl dapps and it is kind of web3.

```
const xrpl = require("xrpl");

const poolSecret = "sEd**********************";
const poolWallet = xrpl.Wallet.fromSeed(poolSecret)

async function main(addr) {
  console.log("Connecting to Testnet...")
  const client = new xrpl.Client('wss://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51233')
  await client.connect()

  // Prepare transaction -------------------------------------------------------
  const prepared = await client.autofill({
    "TransactionType": "Payment",
    "Account": addr,
    "Amount": xrpl.xrpToDrops("1"),
    "Destination": poolWallet.address
  })
  const max_ledger = prepared.LastLedgerSequence
  console.log("Prepared transaction instructions:", prepared)
  console.log("Transaction cost:", xrpl.dropsToXrp(prepared.Fee), "XRP")
  console.log("Transaction expires after ledger:", max_ledger)

  // Sign prepared instructions ------------------------------------------------
  const signed = poolWallet.sign(prepared)
  console.log("Identifying hash:", signed.hash)
  console.log("Signed blob:", signed.tx_blob)

  // Submit signed blob --------------------------------------------------------
  try {
    const tx = await client.submitAndWait(signed.tx_blob)

    // Wait for validation -------------------------------------------------------
    // submitAndWait() handles this automatically, but it can take 4-7s.

    // Check transaction results -------------------------------------------------
    console.log("Transaction result:", tx.result.meta.TransactionResult)
    console.log("Balance changes:", JSON.stringify(xrpl.getBalanceChanges(tx.result.meta), null, 2))

    // End of main()
    client.disconnect()
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

main("rf*******************************");
```

But it returns this error.
This is the full logs.

```
Connecting to Testnet...
Prepared transaction instructions: {
  TransactionType: 'Payment',
  Account: 'rf*******************************',
  Amount: '1000000',
  Destination: 'ra*******************************',
  Flags: 0,
  Sequence: 36726053,
  Fee: '12',
  LastLedgerSequence: 36750914
}
Transaction cost: 0.000012 XRP
Transaction expires after ledger: 36750914
Identifying hash: 79D3030E5C7F53B04C7FD9C4BC0D7D65BEEEAFA2787BB72C87CA8F6B553BA32B
Signed blob: 12000022000000002402306525201B0230C6426140000000000F424068400000000000000C7321EDA47EA21FCF73BF28D57230BCECB075B2A710C0A15E1D49DA2CA30AE672D667067440B5B294834715D70A90DEFECCD66C7AF839FEE250ED078249C2D85315F66D562856025B2812F1285065D4BABC638DC6488F604C4381D9EFF91E6C8795E09E810581144A0CD16399904DE78F0B132D8CC7105091BB911A83143FF554299C3A982782E1201E87E73B0284D73F79

**XrplError: The latest ledger sequence 36750915 is greater than the transaction's LastLedgerSequence (36750914).**
Preliminary result: tefBAD_AUTH
    at /home/barnyjake/work/xrp/node_modules/xrpl/dist/npm/sugar/submit.js:65:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/barnyjake/work/xrp/node_modules/xrpl/dist/npm/sugar/submit.js:5:58) {
  data: undefined
}
```

The address that I use works fine in the wallet.

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and I tried this with node v14 & v16.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

1. From the "bad auth" message
   Change the client you are trying to connect to, try "wss://testnet.xrpl-labs.com/" which explicitly has CORS support (https://xrpl.org/public-servers.html)
2. From the "latest ledger sequence..." message
   **Short answer:** try changing, (or explicitly setting) your Flags value to 2147483648.

**Long answer:**
I had the same error for an "NFTokenCreateOffer" transaction type. It corrected for me when I set the "Flags" property of my transaction to a correct value.

From your output, it looks like your Flags is set to 0 which I don't think matches any true flag for the payment transaction type.

I have a my own system that I have coded that utilizes the "payment" transaction, in which I set Flags to "2147483648" (tfFullyCanonicalSig - https://xrpl.org/transaction-common-fields.html#flags-field), which I know says is deprecated, but it works for me.

My payment transaction looks like this prior to autofill being called:

```
const transaction = {
    TransactionType: 'Payment',
    Account: walletDto.address,
    Amount: amount,
    Destination: sendDetails.sendToAddress,
    Flags: 2147483648, 
  };
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I received this error where I tried to move funds from `Account` -> `Destination` but I wasn't the owner of `"Account": addr,`
In the following function you wrote:

```
const prepared = await client.autofill({
    "TransactionType": "Payment",
    "Account": addr,                   <= // Do you own this wallet ?
    "Amount": xrpl.xrpToDrops("1"),
    "Destination": poolWallet.address  <= // I see above that you own this one
  })
```

If for testing purposes you're trying to just work out this code, try to switch between `addr` and `poolWallet.address`